# Managing MySQL on Desktop?

Tags: mysql, sql

Does anyone know of a simple way to view/edit a .sql file from a Windows computer?

I normally use either phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench for managing databases that are on remote servers.  However, I need to edit a .sql file locally and can't seem to find any software that will let me do this...

Comment: Open it with a text editor for a dirty solution or use heidisql.

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic here, but you can ask it on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: install mysql on your computer?!

Comment: This is for either [softwarerecs.SE] or superuser, superuser.com.

Comment: for example pspad editor

Comment: @GiulioMuscarello: Superuser [does not want Recommendations either](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: .sql files are just text files filled with the DDL and DML for a database dump/export.  You don't usually work with them directly but rather should install an instance of mysql and import the sql file then work with it.  The simplest way possible is to open it with notepad and edit it by hand but it isn't the easiest way, as suggested in the answer below install wamp server is a simple solution to get mysql apache and phpmyadmin in one shot, then just import using phpmyadmin (http://localhost/phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 1):

Download Wampserver!  It has phpmyadmin included

Comment: Downloading an entire server seems quite exaggerate if you only have to edit an .sql file.

Comment: Well PHPMYADMIN needs a HTTP Server and PHP so no its not extreme since he is used to using it, it takes 3mins to install